# Time travel book where the protagonist travels by gazing into a ring

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I was hoping to get help to identify a time travel story. In school, in the 1980s I read a novel where the protagonist gazes into a shiny ring she is wearing and she time travels. It starts with her visiting an old lady who teaches her how to perfect her time travel. She continues traveling until her teacher dies of old age. She solves a puzzle/problems that her teacher gave her and she learns to travel to see her teacher in time frames before she died.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Could it be *[Miracle Island](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0425148793)* by Louise Ladd, first book of the *Anywhere Ring*
series? The Internet Archive doesn't have the first book, but I looked at a few of the other books, and time travel involves her staring into the ring.

### [image: Front cover of Miracle Island]

### Blurb

> The Anywhere Ring is no ordinary ring. With a twist or a turn, and a wish or a dream, it takes you where you want to go... anytime, anywhere! — Miracle Island — It didn't seem fair. Mom and Dad were off on a tropical vacation at Mirabelle Island - and Jenny was stuck at home with her little brother, a mean babysitter, a bunch of stupid boys who made fun of her, and a snowstorm. But that didn't stop Jenny from daydreaming about the beach. She pictured herself surrounded by sunshine, sand, palm trees... and boys. Well, only one boy, but he was really nice and really cute. Too bad it was only a daydream! That's what Jenny thought - until she found seaweed in her hair! And sand between her toes!
>
> That's how Jenny discovered the secret powers of her great-grandmother's ring.
>
> And that's when Jenny and her brother Davy decided to take a little vacation of their own...
>
> To a place they called Miracle Island.